# preg_replace between > and <

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this:

```
<div> 16</div>
```

and I want this:

```
<div><span>16</span></div>
```

Currently, this is the only way I can make it work:

`preg_replace("/(\D)(16)(\D)/", "$1<span>$2</span>$3", "<div> 16</div>")`

If I leave off the $3, I get:

```
<div><span>16</span>/div>
```

Comment: And the problem with your solution is?

Comment: What's the general question being asked? As written, `if ($foo == '<div> 16</div>') $foo = '<div><span>16</span></div>';` is a valid solution.

Comment: I just didn't think my solution was very good, and of course I found a situation where it doesn't work. And I'll fix the order of the parameters, because as noted below the are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following -

```
$str = "<div class=\"number\"> 16</div>";
$formatted_str = preg_replace("/(<div\b[^>]*>)(.*?)<\/div>/i", "$1<span>$2</span></div>", $s);
echo $formatted_str;
```

Comment: preg_replace("/(<.*>)\s*(16)\s*(<.*>)/i', "$1" . '<span class="curPage">' . "$2" . '</span>' . "$3");    This is what I ended up with. Nothing quite covered every situation. There were occasions where the page number was surrounded by other tags.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite sure what your after, but the following is more generic:

```
$value = "<div>    16    </div>";
echo(preg_replace('%(<(\D+)[^>]*>)\s*([^\s]*)\s*(</\2>)%', '\1<span>\3</span>\4', $value));
```

Which would result in:

```
<div><span>16</span></div>
```

Even if the value were:

```
<p>    16    </div>
```

It would result in:

```
<p><span>16</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to say you're using the following:

```
print preg_replace("/(\\D+)(16)(\\D+)/", "$1<span>$2</span>$3", "<div>16</div>");
```

There's nothing wrong with that. $3 is going to contain everything matched in the second (\D+) group. If you leave it off, obviously it's not going to magically appear.

Note that your code in the question had some errors:

1. You need to escape your `\`'s in a string.
2. You need to use `\D+` to match multiple characters.
3. You have a space before 16 in your string, but you're not taking this into account in your regex. I removed the space, but if you want to allow for it you should use `\s*` to match any number of whitespace characters.
4. The order of your parameters was incorrect.

Comment: Escaping `\‍` is only required if it’s part of a valid escape sequence. In this case the `\‍` in `\D` does not need to be escaped as `\D` is not a known escape sequence and thus interpreted as literal string.

Comment: marcog FTW.  Also, if you use single-quoted strings for your regexes, the only characters you have to escape are single-quotes and backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working the best:

```
preg_replace('/(<.*>)\s*('. $page . ')\s*(<.*>)/i', "$1" . '<span class="curPage">' . "$2" . '</span>' . "$3", $pagination)
```

What I found was that I didn't know for sure what tags would precede or follow the page number.